# Center TikZ node relative to path

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, diagrams

I made this diagram in latex, but I can not center the item 'j', corresponding to line 38. Could anyone help me?The diagram of the script is listed below. I tried to use midway on the 38 line, but he centralized the comment in the middle of the page and not in the position where it is located ..

```
% Porter model
% Author: Charles-Axel Dein
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bch} % change default font

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,positioning,shapes.symbols,chains}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[node distance = 1cm, auto,font=\footnotesize,
% STYLES
every node/.style={node distance=3cm},
% The comment style is used to describe the characteristics of each force
comment/.style={rectangle, inner sep= 5pt, text width=4cm, node distance=0.25cm, font=\scriptsize\sffamily},
% The force style is used to draw the forces' name
force/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=black!10, inner sep=5pt, text width=4cm, text badly centered, minimum height=1.2cm, font=\bfseries\footnotesize\sffamily}] 

% Draw forces
\node [force] (z) {Dados Arvore};
\node [force, above of=z] (y) {Dados Originais};
\node [force, right=3cm of z] (x) {Secção};
\node [force, below of=z] (v) {Dados Arvore II};
\node [force, right=3cm of v] (b) {Cubagem};
\node [force, below=3cm of v] (w) {Arquivo Final};
\node [force, below left=1cm of v] (c) {Modelos de Relaçao Hisométrica};
\node [force, below right=1cm of v] (e) {Modelos de Volume};
\node [comment, below=0.5 of y] (j) {Avaliação};
\node [comment, above =0.5 of x] {Avaliação};
\node [comment, below=0.5 of z] (f) {Inconsistências e Manipulação};
\node [comment, below=0.5 of x] (g) {Inconsistências e Manipulação};
\node [comment, above=0.25 of e] {Ajuste};
\node [comment, above=1.5 of e] {Manipulação};
\node [comment, below=0.25 of v] {Ajuste};
\node [comment, above=0.25 of w] {Predição};
\node [comment, below=0.25 of e] {Predição};









% Draw the links between forces
\path[->,thick] 
(y) edge (x)
(v) edge (w)
(v) edge (c)
(v) edge (e)
(c) edge (w)
(b) edge (v)
(f) edge (v)
(e) edge (w)
(g) edge (b)
(j) edge (z);

\path[-,thick] 
(z) edge (f)
(x) edge (g)
(y) edge (j);




\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{Diagrama do Script de ajuste de relação hipsométrica, volume cubado e equações de volumetria da empresa FLORESTECA.  }
\label{fig:6forces}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Could you upload an image and explain what is wrong with the output? As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this? You could set `align=center` as option to the nodes. But I would just delete all their constraints like `inner sep` and `text width`... and use `anchor=base, fill=white`. Like this, you need much less path definitions.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bch} % change default font
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[h]       
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        [% style definitions
        ,every node/.style={node distance=3, font=\footnotesize}
        ,comment/.style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily}
        ,force/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=black!10, inner sep=5pt, text width=3cm, text badly centered, minimum height=1.2cm, font=\bfseries\footnotesize\sffamily}
        ,on grid
        ] 
        % Draw forces
        \node [force] (z) {Dados Arvore};
        \node [force, above = of z] (y) {Dados Originais};
        \node [force, right = 5 of z] (x) {Secção};
        \node [force, below = of z] (v) {Dados Arvore II};
        \node [force, right = 5 of v] (b) {Cubagem};
        \node [force, below = 4 of v] (w) {Arquivo Final};
        \node [force, below left = 2 and 2.5 of v] (c) {Modelos de Relaçao Hisométrica};
        \node [force, below right = 2 and 2.5 of v] (e) {Modelos de Volume};        
        % Draw the links between forces
        \path[->,thick,every node/.append style={comment,anchor=base, fill=white}] 
        (y) edge node {Avaliação} (z) edge node {Avaliação} (x)
        (z) edge node {Inconsistências e Manipulação} (v)
        (v) edge (w) edge node {Ajuste} (c) edge node {Ajuste} (e)
        (c) edge node {Predição} (w)
        (e) edge node {Predição} (w)
        (x) edge node {Inconsistências e Manipulação} (b)
        (b) edge node {Manipulação} (e);        
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \caption[Diagrama do Script de ajuste de relação hipsométrica]{Diagrama do Script de ajuste de relação hipsométrica, volume cubado e equações de volumetria da empresa FLORESTECA.}
        \label{fig:6forces}
    \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MarcoMachado you are very welcome